# Tenable.io CONTAINS filter for assets

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cloud, assets

Is there a way to filter the assets based on the "contains" filter? For example, if an asset has AGENT_NAME set to some text such as "abcdefghijklmnop_extract", and I'm interested in finding assets that have "_extract" as the last word in their name (it is guaranteed the _extract will be at the last of the asset name), is there a way to get the total count of those particular assets? I know Tenable.sc has a CONTAINS filter but I tried searching/finding a similar filter for Tenable.io, but it does not.

Another option would be to export the assets using the API and then go through the assets and check if "_extract" is in AGENT_NAME in python. But this would be way too inefficient if you had lets say 57000 assets. Any suggestions?